# The problem of transfering the array from JS function to the controller method in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, controller

I have one page, one controller, and one JS file. I have the intention to record the content of one span and two tbody elements into six arrays and one variable in order to get the same data in the controller and make new rows in the database tables using these data. Now I have two buttons and each of them use axios.post way to give the needed data out from the js.js file to Database.php file. However only the first one works. The second button makes "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Database.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Database extends Controller
{
public function Publish(Request $request){

    $iduser = $request->session()->get('id');
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kyiv');
    $date = date("Y/m/d");
    $AmountIncome = $request->input('AmountIncome');
    $PriceIncome = $request->input('PriceIncome');
    $AmountExpense = $request->input('AmountExpense');
    $PriceExpense = $request->input('PriceExpense');
    $ItemExpense = $request->input('ItemExpense');
    $ItemIncome = $request->input('ItemIncome');
    $Profit = $request->input('Profit');
    $Profit = floatval($Profit);

    // What I need to do:
    // 1. Insert
    // 2. Create two tables
    // 3. Fill both tables
    $tableprofitname = "profit_" . $iduser;
    DB::table($tableprofitname)->insert([
        'profit' => $Profit,
        'date' => $date,
    ]);
    Schema::create("income_" . $iduser . "_" . strval($date), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('item')->unique();
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->float('price');
    });

    Schema::create("expense_" . $iduser . "_" . strval($date), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('item')->unique();
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->float('price');
    });

    $expenselength = count($ItemExpense);
    $incomelength = count($ItemtIncome);
    for($i = 0;$i<$expenselength;$i++){
        DB::table("expense_" . $iduser . "_" . strval($date))->insert([
            'item' => $ItemExpense[$i],
            'amount' => $AmountExpense[$i],
            'price' => $PriceExpense[$i],
        ]);
    }
    for($i = 0;$i<$incomelength;$i++){
        DB::table("income_" . $iduser . "_" . strval($date))->insert([
            'item' => $ItemIncome[$i],
            'amount' => $AmountIncome[$i],
            'price' => $PriceIncome[$i],
        ]);
    }

    return;
}
}
```

js.js:

```
function C(id, Class, dltnumber) {
cD = [];
columnElements = document.querySelectorAll(id + " " + Class);
number = 0;
columnElements.forEach(function (element) {
    if (dltnumber == null) {
        cD.push(element.value);
    } else {
        if (number != dltnumber) {
            cD.push(element.value);
        }
    }
    number += 1;
});
return cD;
}  
function PostPublish() {
var id = "#tbl-income";
C2_1 = C(id, ".c1");
C2_2 = C(id, ".c2");
C2_3 = C(id, ".c3");
id = "#tbl-expense";
C1_1 = C(id, ".c1");
C1_2 = C(id, ".c2");
C1_3 = C(id, ".c3");
var result = document.getElementById("outcome").innerText;
axios
    .post("/publish", {
        ItemIncome: C2_1,
        IemExpense: C1_1,
        AmountIncome: C2_2,
        PriceIncome: C2_3,
        AmountExpense: C1_2,
        PriceExpense: C1_3,
        Profit: result,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

So the weirdest thing is PostPublish() works only for 4 of 6 arrays. According to my Log file, I get local.ERROR: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given. Just on the line where I try to count the array length of $ItemExpense. The same issue is related to $ItemIncome. The value is null. In the JS code the array isn't empty. I checked this out using alert(). And I can't confirm the $request->input() is the wrong command because it works for all the other 4 arrays.

I'll be grateful for your help.

Comment: You just forgor the "t" here: `IemExpense: C1_1,`. When this happens, the good method is to check the details of your request is the browser's developper tools to check what's sent ;) (after checking the server logs, as you dit all right)

Comment: IemExpense, you have an error in your post key name

Comment: Then I found two mistakes of such sort. I wonder how I couldn't notice independently. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: That's why error logs were invented ;) My personal trick is to use advanced text editors, Notepad++ in my case, that has the great feature of highlighting all other instances of the text you select, so you just select a variable with double-click and if it doesn't highlight everywhere else, there is a typo